# In Node-RED, how do I upload to a node with the given configuration and retrieve the configuration later?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, node-red, watson

I am using Node-RED on Bluemix, I want to let the user upload a document, here is the relevant code fragment in a function/template of a flow

```
<form action="/upload" method="POST">
     <h1>Upload PDF</h1>
<input type="file" name="myFile" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When I run it, I chose a file and press 'submit', but then comes the message
**`Cannot POST /upload`**
Then I went to http://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-http-multipart
, in the example there it says

---

You can upload to a node with the following configuration:

```
[{ "name": "myFile" }]
```

and access the files using the following function on the out port of the node

```
var fields = msg.req.fields;
msg.fields = Object.keys(fields);
var myFile = fields["myFile"][0];
msg.localFilename = myFile.path
...
```

---

1) How can I upload a node with the configuration?

2)Once I get the file name, how do I retrieve it to be sent to the next services? -the next service is 'Conversion' - it takes in the file name.

Comment: I spent a bit of time on this but I couldn't get it working properly either.  However I don't get your Cannot Post error.  Make sure your http-multipart node is on /upload (as per your html) and has a corresponding  http response node.

Comment: Node-Red is an open source code so you may want to try their community to see if you can get an expert there to help  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/node-red

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it work, you need :
1- a classic http node connected to a html node where you put your form :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/fileUploaded" method="POST">
        <input type="file" name="myFile" />
        <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

2- Then you put your HTTP multipart node with Fields :

```
[{ "name": "myFile"}]

You link that node to a function node with the following code :
var fields = msg.req.files;
msg.fields = Object.keys(fields);
var myFile = fields["myFile"][0];
var fs = global.get('fs');
var inStr = fs.createReadStream(myFile.path);
var outStr = fs.createWriteStream('/app/public/upload/testUpload');
inStr.pipe(outStr);
msg.localFilename ='/upload/testUpload'
return msg;
```

You will need to have a folder named "upload" under /app/public/ 
You will also need 'fs' : 
In bluemix-settings.js in functionGlobalContext add     fs:require('fs') 
In package.json, add "fs":"x.x" 
The file will be copied there : /app/public/upload/testUpload 
Then we will be able to access it via msg.localFilename in the next node, for example in a HTML page like this :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Job Done</h1>
        <a href=".{{localFilename}}">File uploaded here</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ah, I see now.  Great answer Romain.

Comment: I highly recommend that you use the "node-red-node-file" node instead of using the _fs_ module directly in a function node.

Answer (score 0):

1. install multer for node-red and then restart node-red.

npm install node-red-contrib-http-multipart

2. After you are done with the installation correctly, you will see httpInMultipart Node.
3. basic html file upload code:

```html
    <form action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
        <input type="file" name="myFile" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

4. httpInMultipart->Function->Http Response Node

Configure the httpInMultipart Node: 
method: POST
url: /upload
Fields: [ { "name": "myFile"} ]

In function node Write the following code:

```js
var file = msg.req.files;
var filesize
msg.test=file;
var localFilenamePath = file.myFile[0].path;
var fileSize = file.myFile[0].size;
var response={};
if(msg.test)
    {
        response.statusCode=0;
        response.localFilenamePath=localFilenamePath;
        response.fileSize = fileSize;
        response.sendMessage="Successful";
    }
else
    {
        response.statusCode=1;
        response.sendMessage="Failed";
    }
msg.payload=response;
return msg;
```

And Voila! We are done!

Comment: Hi @Siena, when I tried to install node http-multipart  i get the following error. any suggestions?                                                                     
 npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Program Files\nodejs\package.json'
npm WARN nodejs No description
npm WARN nodejs No repository field.
npm WARN nodejs No README data
npm WARN nodejs No license field.

Comment: has node been installed correctly?check using node -v

Comment: You might be in the wrong directory when attempting to install the node. Make sure you're in the folder for your project.