# Pick an image from local storage from node red dashboard

Tags: ibm-cloud, dashboard, node-red

I am trying to create a dashboard in bluemix node red where the user can select an image from his local storage and pass it to visual recognition to classify an image.

In node-red flow, there is a file-inject node for uploading a file from local storage, but it has no input nodes.

Is there any method to control the file-inject node programatically, so that when I click a button in dashboard, the file-inject will be triggered and will enable the user to select a file?

Or is there any other method to select a file from local storage and upload it in node red?

Comment: See: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40390822/in-node-red-how-do-i-upload-to-a-node-with-the-given-configuration-and-retrieve/40468356#40468356)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Node-RED, how do I upload to a node with the given configuration and retrieve the configuration later?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40390822/in-node-red-how-do-i-upload-to-a-node-with-the-given-configuration-and-retrieve)